# VBScript - How to sort alpha-numerical string from text file by numerical value?

Tags: sorting, vbscript

My data looks like this:

```
9999.81GB increase - "c:\$RECYCLE.BIN"   1.91GB total
11.54GB increase - "c:\Program Files (x86)"   11.55GB total
101.57GB increase - "c:\Windows"   101.61GB total
```

I want it to look like this:

```
9999.81GB increase - "c:\$RECYCLE.BIN"   1.91GB total
101.57GB increase - "c:\Windows"   101.61GB total
11.54GB increase - "c:\Program Files (x86)"   11.55GB total
```

I've been trying to bubble sort this.  I assume I need to first split off the string before the first "." which will be a usable number for sorting.  I've managed that with something like this:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile1 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Source.txt", ForReading)

Do Until objFile1.AtEndOfStream
FileContent = objFile1.ReadLine
arr1 = Split(FileContent,".",2)
arr2 = Array(arr1(0))

For i=0 to UBound(arr2)
WScript.Echo arr2(i)

Next
Loop
```

But instead of echoing, I need to use these values in the bubble sort.  This is where I seem to be stuck.

I'm open to using a different type of sort.. but there will never be many lines to sort so I figured bubble might be a good choice.

Here is the best I've been able to do:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOpen = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Source.txt", ForReading)

Do Until objOpen.AtEndOfStream
FileContent = objOpen.ReadLine
arr1 = Split(FileContent,".",2)
arr2 = Array(arr1(0))

Do
x = UBound(arr2)
  y = -1
  For j = LBound(arr2) to x - 1
      If arr(j) > arr2(j + 1) Then
         TempValue = arr2(j + 1)
         arr2(j + 1) = arr2(j)
         arr2(j) = TempValue
         y = j
      End If
  Next
  x = y
Loop Until y = -1

z = ""
For i = UBound(arr2) To LBound(arr2)
    z = z & arr2(i) & "." & arr1(1) & vbCrlf

Next  
Loop
 WScript.echo z
```

But this outputs only the last line and it doesn't appear to have even tried to sort.

I'm new at this :)  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Arthur

Comment: Are the units always in GB?

Comment: They are originally in KB are are not labeled as KB.  Via previous processes I've converted them to GB and added the "GB" for easy reading.

But the answer to your question is, yes, in the "source.txt" as it exists now, it will always be GB.

Comment: Note that the numbers used may not make sense (increase vs total)- I manually entered them for testing purposes.

Comment: Okay in this case, here's an idea how to start. Add zero padding to every line to even out the lengths of the numbers. Calculate out how many zeros to add to each line by searching for the dot or the "GB". When the lines are uniform, any sorting method will have an easy time. Final hints: 1) The `String()` function can help you, it repeats a string a specified number of times. 2) It will be much more practical to use `.ReadAll()` and `Split()` than to use `.ReadLine()` in a loop to painstakingly build an array of lines.

Comment: If you have control of the the preprocess it should be no problem to right align the numbers, even a character sort will always have spaces before digits. I'd done this in first place.

Comment: I was able to find a solution using Tomalak's leading zeroes idea.  I couldn't get it to work using .ReadAll.  Here's what I did:

Comment: Hit enter too soon.

I was able to find a solution using Tomalak's leading zeroes idea.  I couldn't get it to work using .ReadAll.  Here's what I did:

    Const ForReading = 1
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile1 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Source.txt", ForReading)
    Set objFile2 = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Result.txt")
    Do Until objFile1.AtEndOfStream
    Line = objFile1.ReadLine
    Split1 = Split(Line,".",2)
    Split2 = Split1(0)

    result = string(7 - Len(Split2), "0") & Line
    objFile2.Write result & vbCrlf

    Loop

Comment: I guess I can't put this in a comment.  I'll answer myself I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read it a couple of times and, it seems to me, the question is "Why does it not sort?"

*"But this outputs only the last line and it doesn't appear to have even tried to sort."*

The answer is simple: you are trying to sort data from one line only. Here is the outline of your algorithm in pseudo code:

```
Read line by line (outer loop)
  extract the number and place it into arr2
  bubble sort algorithm on top of arr2 that contains data for 1 line only(inner loop) 
end outer loop
```

I got to my windows box so here is a working version in VBScript.The most complicated part is getSize() function as it has to do careful parsing of the string to extract the size. I thrown in the size unit conversion as well to support GB, MB and KB.

```
' -----------------------------------------------------------'
' the most complicated part: extracts size info form the string
Function getSize (line)
    kbSize = 0

    ' check that there is a data in the line
    if Len(line) <> 0 then
        arr = Split(line," ")
        ' extract the size and the unit of measurement
        size = Left(arr(0), Len(arr(0))-2)
        unit = UCase(Right(arr(0), 2))
        ' convert all sizes to KBs
        select case unit
            case "GB"
                kbSize = size * 1024 * 1024
            case "MB"
                kbSize = size * 1024
            case "KB"
                kbSize = size
            case else 
                Err.raise 101, "getSize", "do not recignize the size unit " + unit + " in the line " + line
        end select
    end if

    ' remember that the size is not integer
    getSize = CDbl(kbSize)
End Function

' -----------------------------------------------------------'
' your main program flow

Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile1 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Source.txt", ForReading)

' slurp the whole file into memory
content = objFile1.ReadAll
'split file into arry line by line
lines = Split(content, vbCrLf)

' bubble sort lines to avoid brain strain
For i = LBound(lines) to UBound(lines)
  For j = i+1 to UBound(lines)
      If getSize(lines(i)) < getSize(lines(j)) Then
         TempValue = lines(i)
         lines(i) = lines(j)
         lines(j) = TempValue
      End If
  Next
Next

' get the sorted array and join it back into string for easy of output
output = Join(lines, vbCrLf)
WScript.echo output
```

Comment: I removed the KB conversion and case piece as I will always have the GB values to work with.

Previously, I always had issues feeding the split lines from .ReadAll into the sort.  Your function method solved this problem

Comment: Glad to be of help. We tend to forget how confusing the whole programming zoo could be in the beginning. But it gets easier with time. :)
I also want to comment that Noodles's solution is perfectly correct and can be even better in a more complicated situation. It is just a little bit too much for this specific case, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a recordset, they can be created in memory, then sorted and filtered. It uses a regular expression to look for what MIGHT be number or a date. The RegEx assumes English numbers and dates, change if that's not the case.

It's part of a larger program so param1 is ignored here.

It uses redirection rather than opening and closing files. It MUST be run with CSCript for that reason.

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    If LCase(Arg(1)) = "n" then
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "SortKey", 4 
        .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Lne = Inp.readline
            SortKey = Mid(Lne, LCase(Arg(3)), LCase(Arg(4)) - LCase(Arg(3)))
            If IsNumeric(Sortkey) = False then
                Set RE = new Regexp
                re.Pattern = "[^0-9\.,]"
                re.global = true
                re.ignorecase = true
                Sortkey = re.replace(Sortkey, "")
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Sortkey) = False then
                Sortkey = 0
            ElseIf Sortkey = "" then
                Sortkey = 0
            ElseIf IsNull(Sortkey) = true then
                Sortkey = 0
            End If
            .AddNew
            .Fields("SortKey").value = CSng(SortKey)
            .Fields("Txt").value = Lne
            .UpDate
        Loop
        If LCase(Arg(2)) = "a" then SortColumn = "SortKey ASC"
        If LCase(Arg(2)) = "d" then SortColumn = "SortKey DESC"
        .Sort = SortColumn
        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

    ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "d" then
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "SortKey", 4 
        .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Lne = Inp.readline
            SortKey = Mid(Lne, LCase(Arg(3)), LCase(Arg(4)) - LCase(Arg(3)))
            If IsDate(Sortkey) = False then
                Set RE = new Regexp
                re.Pattern = "[^0-9\\\-:]"
                re.global = true
                re.ignorecase = true
                Sortkey = re.replace(Sortkey, "")
            End If
            If IsDate(Sortkey) = False then
                Sortkey = 0
            ElseIf Sortkey = "" then
                Sortkey = 0
            ElseIf IsNull(Sortkey) = true then
                Sortkey = 0
            End If
            .AddNew
            .Fields("SortKey").value = CDate(SortKey)
            .Fields("Txt").value = Lne
            .UpDate
        Loop
        If LCase(Arg(2)) = "a" then SortColumn = "SortKey ASC"
        If LCase(Arg(2)) = "d" then SortColumn = "SortKey DESC"
        .Sort = SortColumn
        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With


    ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "t" then
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "SortKey", 201, 260 
        .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Lne = Inp.readline
            SortKey = Mid(Lne, LCase(Arg(3)), LCase(Arg(4)) - LCase(Arg(3)))
            .AddNew
            .Fields("SortKey").value = SortKey
            .Fields("Txt").value = Lne
            .UpDate
        Loop
        If LCase(Arg(2)) = "a" then SortColumn = "SortKey ASC"
        If LCase(Arg(2)) = "d" then SortColumn = "SortKey DESC"
        .Sort = SortColumn
        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
    ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "tt" then
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "SortKey", 201, 260 
        .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Lne = Inp.readline
            SortKey = Trim(Mid(Lne, LCase(Arg(3)), LCase(Arg(4)) - LCase(Arg(3))))
            .AddNew
            .Fields("SortKey").value = SortKey
            .Fields("Txt").value = Lne
            .UpDate
        Loop
        If LCase(Arg(2)) = "a" then SortColumn = "SortKey ASC"
        If LCase(Arg(2)) = "d" then SortColumn = "SortKey DESC"
        .Sort = SortColumn
        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
    End If
```

**Sort**

```
filter Sort {n|d|t|tt} {a|d} startcolumn  endcolumn
```

Sorts a file

```
n - extracts a number from the columns specified. Looks for the first number.
d - extracts a time or date from the columns specified. Looks for the first date.
t - extracts a text string including spaces from the columns specified.
tt - extracts a text string discarding leading and trailing spaces from the columns specified.

a - sorts acending
d - sorts decending

startcolumn - the starting column, the first character is column 1

endcolumn - the ending column
```

**Example**

```
cscript //nologo filter.vbs sort n a 1 11 < "%windir%\win.ini"
```

See filter.zip at https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvqkaKIXzvDieQFjUcKneSZhDjw which is full of VBS text processing routines.

- Filter a file by regular expresion
- Find and replace text in a file using regular expresions. Also extracts substrings from a file
- Filter and select previous and next lines

**Use VBScript Expressions**

- Run vbscript with it's text specified on the command line against each line

**Sorting**

- Sorts a file numerically, alphabetically, or by date
- Randomise the lines in a file to unsort
- Removes duplicate lines in a file
- Reverses the text in lines for reverse searching
- Swaps the order of lines in a file

**Blank Lines and Spaces**

- Trim blank lines from top or bottom of files
- Trim leading and trailing spaces
- Removes all blank lines from a file
- Fix line endings

**General**

- Speak the text aloud
- Convert HTML to text
- Removes or leaves a specified number of lines from top or bottom of a file
- Write StdIn to a file and StdOut
- Counts the lines in a file and sets an environmental variable with the count

**Clipboard and Web Server**

Filter can also act a a source writing to StdOut.

- Writes the contents of the clipboard to StdOut
- Writes the contents of a specified web page to StdOut

Comment: Thanks Noodles.  This one is pretty hard for me to follow as I am a beginner.  I'll look it over and try to understand.

Comment: Remember the code is repetitive to allow easy copying and pasting of only the part you need. There are 4 stand alone sections - numbers, dates, text, and trimmed text with each section standing on it's own. So just take the numbers section. and delete the dates and text sections.

Comment: http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution using Tomalak's leading zeroes idea.  I couldn't get it to work using .ReadAll.  Here's what I did:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile1 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Source.txt", ForReading)
Set objFile2 = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Result.txt")
Do Until objFile1.AtEndOfStream
Line = objFile1.ReadLine
Split1 = Split(Line,".",2)
Split2 = Split1(0)

result = string(7 - Len(Split2), "0") & Line
objFile2.Write result & vbCrlf

Loop
```

From here I just sort it with a Windows Command Prompt sort.

I know this may not be ideal.. but it works!  Thanks Tomalak!

If you get bored and want to show me a better way, please do.  Remember... I am attempting to learn as I go and am at a very basic level... so please go easy with the explanations :)

Arthur